# Find the first five occurence of unique values and implement them into aggregation functions

Tags: postgresql

As the title said, I need to find the first five occurence of each value in my table and then aggregate them.

**Table structure:**

| user_id | booking_created_time | booking_paid_time | booking_price_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

**Code:**

```
select x.user_id, row_number() over(partition by x.user_id order by x.booking_created_time) 
as booking_sequence, x.booking_created_time::date as booking_created_date, x.booking_price_amount, 
sum(y.booking_price_amount) as total_booking_price_amount from 
(
    select user_id, booking_created_time, booking_price_amount from fact_flight_sales 
    group by user_id, booking_created_time, booking_price_amount 
) as x
join 
(
    select user_id, booking_price_amount 
    from fact_flight_sales group by user_id, booking_price_amount
) as y
on x.user_id = y.user_id
group by x.user_id, x.booking_created_time, x.booking_price_amount 
having count(x.user_id) >= 1 and sum(y.booking_price_amount) >25000000 
order by total_booking_price_amount desc, booking_sequence asc;
```

The output that I have now looks like
**Sample output:**

| user_id | booking_sequence | booking_created_date | booking_price_amount | total_booking_price_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sforlongf | 1 | 2017-05-21 | 8257056 | 39826576 |
| sforlongf | 2 | 2017-09-19 | 8449307 | 39826576 |
| sforlongf | 3 | 2018-01-08 | 8677950 | 39826576 |
| sforlongf | 4 | 2018-09-01 | 4317539 | 39826576 |
| sforlongf | 5 | 2018-09-16 | 6196224 | 39826576 |
| sforlongf | 6 | 2018-12-16 | 3928500 | 39826576 |
| smassy0 | 1 | 2017-04-09 | 9109669 | 33241207 |
| smassy0 | 2 | 2017-06-11 | 2609767 | 33241207 |
| smassy0 | 3 | 2018-03-31 | 9809016 | 33241207 |
| smassy0 | 4 | 2018-11-02 | 7223492 | 33241207 |
| smassy0 | 5 | 2018-11-06 | 4489263 | 33241207 |

As you can see, sforlongf has 6 occurences, how do I limit it's occurence to 5 and make it affect the total_booking_price_amount?

I just can't get the table to work! Sorry about that! It works in preview :/

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work by adding a number_row() into each subquery and limiting it

```
select x.user_id, row_number() over(partition by x.user_id order by x.booking_created_time) 
as booking_sequence, x.booking_created_time::date as booking_created_date, x.booking_price_amount, 
sum(y.booking_price_amount) as total_booking_price_amount from 
(
    select user_id, booking_created_time, booking_price_amount, row_number() over(partition by 
    user_id order by booking_created_time) 
    as booking_sequence from fact_flight_sales 
    group by user_id, booking_created_time, booking_price_amount 
) as x 
join 
(
      select user_id, booking_price_amount, row_number() over(partition by 
      user_id order by booking_created_time) as booking_sequence
      from fact_flight_sales order by booking_created_time
) as y
on x.user_id = y.user_id where x.booking_sequence<=5 and y.booking_sequence<=5
group by x.user_id, x.booking_created_time, x.booking_price_amount 
having count(x.user_id) >= 1 and sum(y.booking_price_amount) >25000000 
order by total_booking_price_amount desc, booking_sequence asc;
```